# Pointers, References and the other one

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, reference

I'm learning about references and pointers and variables. I think I've gotten myself lost.

At a high level, my understanding is

> *pointer = "points" to the location in memory
>
> &reference = references the values

So, this means

```
char* c;     //pointer
char& c;     //reference
char c;      //does this not have a flash name? What is the prefix?
```

If the pointer is the "location" (as per my description above) and the reference is the value, then what is `char c` ? Both? Or just the value? My tests indicate value only, so if this is true, why do we use `reference`?

EG, why would I use

```
void myFunction(int& size);
```

over

```
void myFunction(int size);
```

Comment: "I think that we only typically use pointers and references when sticking items on the stack (which means making them public)" - No thats wrong, where did you read this? How is allocation related to public/private?

Comment: *All* are variables. Even constants declared like e.g. `const int c;` are called variables. The thing is the *prefix*, a *reference* variable, a *pointer* variable, a *constant* variable (no matter how oxymoronic that last is). It also doesn't matter where they are declared or defined, a variable is still a variable.

Answer (score 5):

Let me give your variables unique names, so it is easier to talk about them:

```
char  a = 'x';
char& b = a;
char* c = &a;
```

In this example, `a` is the name for a fresh box with the code of the character 'x' stored inside it:

```
  +-----+
a | 120 |
  +-----+
```

And `b` is just another name for the same box:

```
  +-----+
a | 120 | b
  +-----+
```

Finally, `c` is the name of a box containing a pointer to the first box:

```
  +-----+
a | 120 | b
  +-----+
     ^
     |
  +--|--+
c |  |  |
  +-----+
```

Comment: This is wonderful but I think it explains my question better (meaning my question is clearly not clear). If `b` is another name for the same box, then why do we have it? We can pass variables (references or not) around so why do we need to declare it's a reference when we use (to use .net terminology) a value type?

Comment: A parameter of type `char x` is an independent copy, a second box. If you want to change what's inside the caller's box, you don't want a second box, you want a second name for the same box. That's what a parameter of type `char& x` means.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, variables are unconstrained. Variables can themselves *be* objects, or they can be references bound to objects. In either case, the *value* of the variable (i.e the result of evaluating the id-expression that consists solely of the name of the variable) is that object. If a variable is an object, then its storage is either automatic (for non-static block local variables) or static/thread-local otherwise. References do not have storage. The lifetime of a variable is the lifetime of its name; if the variable is an object, then that is also the lifetime of the object.

In general, every (destructible) object type can be the type of a variable in C++. This is different from many other languages, in which variables are constrained to either be of some kind of "primitive" type or otherwise be references to objects that are located elsewhere.

As for pointers: pointers are nothing special, they're just ordinary objects, like floats or strings. The fact that pointer values have a certain meaning is no different from the fact that, say, integer values have a certain meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from `vector myVector={...million elements...};`. What this does is declaring a variable with a specific name (myVector) and a specific type (vector of strings).

For the time being, we don't actually care how/where this variable is stored.

We have a method that accepts vector of strings `int calculate(vector vs) { }` .

When we call `calculate(myVector)` the myVector VALUE is copied inside the function and the function proceeds with the execution.

In that case, we just copied a vector of million strings for no good reason. By specifying that calculate takes a REFERENCE to a vector `calculate(vector & vs)` we can omit that copy and pass just a ... reference to the vector, not its actual value.

Now, reference can be understood as the "location" of myVector, but that wouldn't be entirely correct as this is usually an implementation detail and we don't have (we shouldn't) worry about implementation details. The main point is that we pass a "reference-to-something" instead of "something".

Why not pointers though? By using pointers the whole thing becomes explicit. We denote that the methods accepts a memory location in which a vector of strings is stored. This may be valid under certain circumstances (e.g. your method accepts null pointers) but usually passing a reference is cleaner and more robust.

Recapping

`vector myVector = {...values...};` = a variable with a specific type name and value

`vector & myVector` = a reference to an EXISTING vector of strings

`vector * myVector` = a pointer to a vector of strings

Answer (score -1):

As I see it -

> "char c"

is **only a declaration** that every time the compiler will compile your code it will know that *'c'* is a char.
Now, after assigning a value to *c* - if you want to refer to *'c'* from a different place, you could do it in two ways: by reference or by its pointer.

Comment: it does not have to be in a different place. There are several use cases of needing a pointer/reference of a "normal" variable all in the same place.

Comment: No. `char c;` is a **definition**. It makes the variable known to the code, allocates memory for storage, but doesn't assign a value. A **declaration** would be `extern char c;`.